# I can't connect to firebase

Tags: android, firebase, intellij-idea

I added firebase sdk to my android app 1 hour ago and followed the steps.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAkZ4.png)

but on the last step, until now it is still verifying.

what does it mean that i may need to uninstall and reinstall the app?
what app?

Comment: You can skip that step and start using your project.

Comment: @Ma.Hidie P. Lacanaria please proceed as per this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup). To verify the Notifier app, you need to run your Notifier app on an emulator that has network access, the Firebase console notifies you that your app connection is complete.

Answer (score 0):

In tools go to Firebase and see Firebase is connected or not:

[image]

Comment: i cant see any firebase in tools

Comment: btw im using intellij idea

Comment: In Android Studio, go to tools